# Why doesn't my UILabel change when I press the button?

Tags: swift

By pressing a button in my app, the value of a variable falls by 3. While this happens without any issues, the label which uses string interpolation to show that variable as its text (label.text) does not reflect the change.

How can I make it so pressing the button changes the value of the UILabel?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var token = 5

let theButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("button", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .systemPink
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(theButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

@objc func theButtonPressed() {
    if token >= 3 {
        token -= 3
    print("ok done")
    } else {
    print("nope")
    }
}

lazy var tokenLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(token)"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

    view.addSubview(tokenLabel)
    view.addSubview(theButton)

    theButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    theButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    theButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    theButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    tokenLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    tokenLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    tokenLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    tokenLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}    
}
```

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at the first line of button pressed function and see what the value of token is at the first hit. Add another breakpoint at print ok function and continue execrations and see if it runs

Comment: Are you saying that the you see "ok done" first, but then you see "nope" the second time you press the button? Because that's what I would expect.

Comment: @Andrew yes that is correct, but the issue is that my tokenLabel.text does not change to reflect the new number, that is 2 (5-3 = 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the label's text when the button is pressed.

```swift
@objc func theButtonPressed() {
    if token >= 3 {
        token -= 3
        print("ok done")
        tokenLabel.text = "\(token)" // <- update
    } else {
        print("nope")
    }
}
```

Or, you can observe the property `token` and change the label when a new value is set.

```swift
var token = 5 {
    didSet {
        tokenLabel.text = "\(token)"
    }
}

@objc func theButtonPressed() {
    if token >= 3 {
        token -= 3
        print("ok done")
    } else {
        print("nope")
    }
}
```

Comment: @swiftnjava Glad it worked. ```didSet``` and ```willSet``` are property observers. They observe and respond to changes in a property's value. ```willSet``` is called just before the value is set while ```didSet``` is called after the new value is stored. You can find a lot of info on this online. Here is one: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html